# Initializer list in constructor to initialize private const c string error

Tags: c++, string, constructor, initializer-list

my private members in my class:

```
const char arr1[];
const char arr2[];
```

my constructor:

```
className(const char a[], const char b[])
   :arr1(a), arr2(b)
{

}
```

The error message from console window is:

```
In constructor className::className(const char*, const char*):
error: incompatible types in assignment of const char* to const char [0]
```

Please help, what am I doing wrong?

---

On a side note, I found a solution...
I used pointers as my private member vars, so *arr1 and *arr2 and that worked. :)

Comment: C++ doesn't allow arrays in classes without an explicit size.

Comment: If you need a dynamic size make the class into a template and then when you construct it you can set the size.  Or you could malloc the memory and then copy the array inside thje constructor instead of using an initializer list.

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring your members as `const char arr1[]`. I am suprised that the compiler is even allowing you to make that declaration, as it should have had a fixed size in that form (like `const char arr1[512]`).

Depending on what you want to do, you'll either have to:

1. declare your members as `const char* arr1` -- note that this will *not* copy the strings; or
2. use a string class (like `std::string`) and/or allocate memory for the class member, and copy

Comment: Yes, #2 is the way to go in most cases, but it does depend on what one is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you compiler should already choke on declarations of the members:

```
const char arr1[];
const char arr2[];
```

That's illegal C++, arrays as class members need to have their size spelled out.

Second, `const char p[]`, when used in function declarations, literaly means `const char* p`. That is, a pointer to constant char. Arrays are not pointers, don't confuse the two. They *decay* to a pointer to their first element when passed to functions, though.